# installing wireless returns error

Tags: wireless

I downloaded compat-wireless to install wireless but when I write - make - in terminal it returns this :

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-23-generic-pae/build M=/home/linz/Mine/compat-wireless-2012-12-18 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic-pae'
scripts/Makefile.build:44: /home/linz/Mine/compat-wireless-2012-12-18/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[4]: *** No rule to make target `/home/linz/Mine/compat-wireless-2012-12-18/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/Makefile'.  Stop.
make[3]: *** [/home/linz/Mine/compat-wireless-2012-12-18/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx] Error 2
make[2]: *** [/home/linz/Mine/compat-wireless-2012-12-18/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros] Error 2
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/linz/Mine/compat-wireless-2012-12-18] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic-pae'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

what shall I do?

Comment: I installed lan then reboot.

Comment: Do you have the package build-essential installed?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have better luck installing the compat-wireless suite in the Ubuntu repositories. With a working internet connection, please do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.12-precise-generic-pae
```

After it is installed, reboot. If your wireless is not working, post the details and we'll troubleshoot:

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280
```

I believe the correct driver for your 14e4:4365 device is `bcmwl-kernel-source` in versions 6.20.155.1 and newer. I suggest you try:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

If it doesn't start your wireless, tell us what version was installed:

```
sudo dpkg -s bcmwl-kernel-source | grep Version
```

Comment: 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:4365] (rev 01) = the output

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Version: 6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu0.0.2

Comment: I reboot, but neither I can connect to Internet via Lan nor Wireless when I click on network icon ( top-right of desktop ) it's written no network device available what I do? :(

Comment: You can get your ethernet back with: sudo modprobe b44. Are there any clues here? dmesg | grep wl

Comment: your codes didn't work

Comment: Let's try to troubleshoot the ethernet first. What is is? lspci -nn | grep 0200 Thanks.

Comment: returns : 02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: atheros Communications Inc. Device [1969:10a0] (rev 10)

Comment: I re-install Ubuntu then I installed Lan and Wifi and I could work with Wifi and Lan but system hanged up then I had to reboot it after reboot I have that problem again :(

Comment: Your ethernet uses the driver _alx_. Load it and see if there are any errors: sudo modprobe alx Then look for messages in the log: dmesg | grep alx Thanks.

Comment: when I type this sudo modprobe alx returns : FATAL : Module alx not found

Comment: can I have your email to chat! I think its better! plz

Comment: It's in my profile.

Comment: I couldn't find plz write it here! thx

Comment: wrweston@ubuntu.com

Comment: you don't have gmail? so How can I connect you by gmail?

Comment: I guess you can't. Why not just email??

Comment: you mean sending email? ok...

Comment: I sent an email to you